# syntax error on logout script?

Tags: php, mysql, logout

I have a problem with my logout script. It works fine, if a user presses logout it kills the session and goes to logout.php where the user is told they've been logged out.

But when the browser cache is emptied or if the site should not be connected to the internet and if a user clicks the logout button it comes up with this error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

It fails beacause it cant set logout to '1' so i want to know how i might go about putting an else statement in somewhere to say redirect to logout.php so i don't get that horrible syntax error message.

Here's my code:

```
<?php   
ob_start();
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');
    require('includes/functions.php');  
?>

<?php
session_start();

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Offline' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
?>

<?php
    // Four steps to closing a session
    // (i.e. logging out)

    // 1. Find the session

    // 2. Unset all the session variables
    $_SESSION = array();

    // 3. Destroy the session cookie
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
    }

    // 4. Destroy the session
    session_destroy();

    redirect_to("login.php?logout=1");

    ob_end_flush()
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have double quotes and you should be using single quotes

Change this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Offline' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."")
```

To:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Offline' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'")
```

**PLEASE NOTE** You should replace all your `mysql_*` functions. As of `PHP 5.5.0` they are deprecated. Use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: generally IDs are stored as integers, so I don't think you'll want single quotes around the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something wrong with your quotes: As long as the user_id is an integer value you could do it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Offline' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
```

In case it is a string, switch to single quotes:

```
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online="Offline" WHERE id="'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"');
```